# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Data is retrieved but not saved into database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am creating an Asp.Net core web application. I have successfully connected database to my app. I can run all the migration successfully and even retrieve data from database. But when I try to save data using my DbContext data is not saved in the database. Here is my code

**Category Model Class**

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Category Controller**

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext dbContext;

    public CategoryController(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var categories = dbContext.Categories.ToList();
        return View(categories);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Category category)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dbContext.Categories.Add(category);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
 </form>
```

**DbContext Class**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

and finally my **ConfigureServices Method in Startup** file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbContext")));
    }
```

I successfully get data in the Index method that I have manually stored in database but cannot save from a form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is necessary to call `SaveChanges()` method of EntityFramework to save data:

```
dbContext.Categories.Add(category);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

It is necessary to call `SaveChanges` after creating, updating, deleting operations.

Comment: Thank you. Is it necessary after update and remove too?

Comment: @AwaisSaeed yeah, it is necessary to call  `SaveChanges` after creating, updating, deleting operations.

Answer (score 0):

> In Entity Framework, the `DbContext.SaveChanges()` method saves all changes made in the context of the database.

So after adding, updating or deleting data you need call `SaveChages()` method:

```
dbContext.Categories.Add(category);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

for knowing more about `SaveChange()` you can follow this [link](https://entityframework.net/save-changes).