# Data is retrieved but is not getting saved or updated ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-core

My questions is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876569/asp-net-core-3-1-data-is-retrieved-but-not-saved-into-database) but I've applied the answers and it's still not working and I've used a slightly different approach while storing the data in the DB.

**Employee Model Class**

```
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Type script code related to saving**

```
private urlSaveEmployee = '/employee/save';

private save() {
        try {

            const employee = this.createEmployee();
            Util.request(this.urlSaveEmployee, 'post', 'json', (response) => {
                if (response != null) {
                    $.notify(response.message);
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $.notify(response.message);
                    console.error('Failed to get data #T7G985. Please try again.');
                }
            }, () => {
            }, employee);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }

    private createEmployee() {
        try {

            const employee = {
                EmployeeId: $('#employee_id').val(),
                Firstname: $('#first_name').val(),
                Lastname: $('#last_name').val()
            };
            return employee;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
```

**Save button View code**

```
<tr>
                <td style="width: 100px">First Name*</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" id="employee_id" value="@Employee.EmployeeId" />
                    <input class="form-control-sm w-100" id="first_name" value="@Employee.FirstName" autocomplete="off" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px">Last Name*</td>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control-sm w-100" id="last_name" value="@Employee.LastName" autocomplete="off" />
                </td>
            </tr>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary employee-form-save" id="save_form">
                        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="margin-right:5px"></i>
                        Save
                    </button>
```

**Controller code related to Save**

```
        [HttpPost("employee/save")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SaveEmployee(Employee employee) {
            try
            {
                Employee employeeFromDb = await _db.Employees.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.EmployeeId == employee.EmployeeId);

                if (employeeFromDb == null)
                {
                    _db.Employees.Add(employee);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Successfully" });
                } else {
                    _db.Employees.Update(employee);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Updated Successfully" });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error while saving" });
            }
        }
```

When I click on save button it reloads the page without changes. I added breakpoints and according to that the `employeeFromDb` is clearly going in the `.Update` clause but it just refreshes the page and the Database remains unchanged. Here is the screenshot at that breakpoint:
[image]

Comment: In my experience the most common cause of "the code says the data should be there but the database says it ain't so" is the user (you) is looking in the wrong database.  Check your connection strings.  Check what database you have open for viewing.

Comment: @SamAxe but the correct data is getting retrieved from the same connecting strings.

Comment: Yeah.  I'll let you ponder that one for a bit.

Comment: @SamAxe no I mean is it possible? That the data is getting retrieved correctly but not while storing... I'm actually new to ASP.NET.

Comment: Anything - literally any.. well.. like 2% of thing... no.. hmmm.. SOME things are definitely possible.  The thing you describe sounds like one of those possible things.

Comment: Are you sure employee record from db is actually returning a record with the same Id? Or is it returning a default value for employee object, ie EmployeeId is 0  and then trying to update a record that doesn't exist wouldn't do anything to your database.

Comment: it is returning the correct value. The employee id is not 0 I've checked that using break points. @Alejandro I think the problem is in `public async Task<IActionResult> SaveEmployee(Employee employee)` can you check if I'm missing anything? Because the more I'm searching I'm getting things like `ModelState` which I've no idea what it is and it made me question that function in controller.

Comment: Have you tried setting the properties of employeeFromDb to the values from your employee object instead? employeeFromDb.FirstName = employee.FirstName; and then add employeeFromDb to the update/add methods. Also have you put breakpoint inside the catch block? Nothing is throwing exception?

Comment: @Alejandro no I've not tried that I'm directly updating the retrieved object in save function, but let me try that now.

Comment: @Alejandro it worked :D post is as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: If your page is still refreshing on button click then refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465557/how-to-stop-page-reload-on-button-click-jquery/33465621, You may need to add `e.preventDefault();` in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad it worked, so that was just a test. What you were finding about EntityState is really what you should read on from this tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-3.1

> Entity States
>   The database context keeps track of whether entities in memory are in
>   sync with their corresponding rows in the database, and this
>   information determines what happens when you call the SaveChanges
>   method. For example, when you pass a new entity to the Add method,
>   that entity's state is set to Added. Then when you call the
>   SaveChanges method, the database context issues a SQL INSERT command.

If you look at the Edit example where Bind properties are passed along with the parameter Id of the record, you could probably use that as a better example for your work. However, if you would like to create a mapper class to convert your request object into an Entity Framework object so it gets updated correctly that could work too. I wonder if you were actually getting an exception before but missed it since the breakpoint wasn't on that block.

This could be useful too if binding through Ajax json calls - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60180783/8161471